# Passing Variable from one WPF Window to Another (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I really feel bad for having to ask this. The answer should probably be obvious; however, I have searched here and on Google to no avail.

I am quite new to WPF. With Windows Forms, I recall it was quite easy to pass data between Windows, but I cannot figure it out with my WPF application.

I am simply building an application for myself that will allow me to access and insert data in a MySQL database. When the button I have added to view all the records in a table is clicked, I want a new window to open. This window will simply display all the data; the table will be selected in MainWindow.

The problem I have is this: I need someway for the secondary window (View) to know which table was selected. I will probably use a ListBox control for table selection, but at the end of the day it really does not matter. Eventually, the value will be stored as a string in a variable. I need the View window to be able to access this string so it knows which table to query. In example:

// Main Window

```
private void viewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var table = "DS";
                View viewWindow = new View();
                viewWindow.Show();                
        }
```

// View Window

```
private void windowLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseConnection myConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
        List<string>[] result = myConnection.Select(table);

        text.Text = MainWindow.test + (result[0][0] + " " + result[1][0] + " " + result[2][0] + " " + result[3][0]);

    }
```

All I need to do is to pass the value of table (which will vary in the final application based on user input), to View. For example, I need it so that in the above code, the following would be executed:

```
List<string>[] result = myConnection.Select("DS");
```

I feel like this should be obvious and easy, but I am not sure how to accomplish this. I would sincerely appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you needing to do this the MVVM way or just spawning a new view from another view using code behind?

Comment: The good habit is to keep one window throughout the application. WPF exposes ContentControl which allows altering view based on some criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a variable through constructor, like this

```
public View(string table)
{
     this.table = table;
}
```

And when you initialize your window:

```
var table = "DS";
View viewWindow = new View(table);
viewWindow.Show();
```